# Laravel listener listen to multiple event

Tags: events, laravel, laravel-5

So according to the laravel event [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events), when defining listeners, it can receive the event instance in their handle method and perform any logic necessary:

```
public function handle(FoodWasPurchased $event)
```

So if my **FoodWasPurchased** event is defined as below (assumed EventServiceProvider is set):

```
public function __construct(Food $food)
{
    $this->food = $food;
}
```

I could access the *$food* in event from listener by doing:

```
$event->food->doSomething();
```

But now my question is what if a listener listen to multiple events?

```
Event FoodWasPurchased -> Listener Bill
Event DrinksWasPurchased -> Listener Bill
```

What I did now is I did not specify the event instance in the listener handle method:

```
public function handle($event)
```

where I can later use an if condition to check what is received in the $event:

```
if (isset($event->food)) {

    // Do something...

} elseif (isset($event->drinks)) {

    // Do something else...

}
```

I'm sure there is a better way.

Or the best practice is ensure that one listener only listens to one single event ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can listen to multiple events by using [Event Subscribers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#event-subscribers) which are placed in the Listeners folder but are capable of listening to multiple events.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

class UserEventListener{
    /**
     * Handle user login events.
     */
    public function onUserLogin($event) {}

    /**
     * Handle user logout events.
     */
    public function onUserLogout($event) {}

    /**
     * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
     *
     * @param  Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return array
     */
    public function subscribe($events){
        $events->listen(
            'App\Events\UserLoggedIn',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogin'
        );

        $events->listen(
            'App\Events\UserLoggedOut',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogout'
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: how can we call this class from controller?

Comment: EventListeners are triggered when the corresponding event is raised. So you have to trigger the event within the controller.

Answer (score 17):

If your events conform to a contract or interface it seems you can pass as many as you like to a listener...

```
class MyEventOne extends Event implements MyEventInterface
```

Then in the EventServiceProvider you connect up your events and listeners as so...

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\MyEventOne' => [
        'App\Listeners\MyListener',
    ],
    'App\Events\MyEventTwo' => [
        'App\Listeners\MyListener',
    ],
];
```

And finally in your listener you type hint your handler to accept the event object based on the contract/interface...

```
public function handle(MyEventInterface $event)
```

I've unit tested this, it may not be appropriate for every scenario, but it seems to work. I hope it helps.

Comment: this solution is very clean and enforces interfaces. ++

Answer (score 8):

You may try something like this as well:

```php
// Instead of Food or Drink use parent Type
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DrinWasPurchased extends Event
{
    // Instead of Food or Drink typehint Model        
    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        // Instead of $this->food or $this->drink use a generic name
        $this->item = $model;
    }
}
```

Then in the `handle` method of listener try something like this:

```php
public function handle(\App\Events\Event $event)
{
    if($event->item instanceof \App\Food)
    {
        $item->eat(); // Just an example
    }

    if($event->item instanceof \App\Drink)
    {
        $item->drink(); // Just an example
    }
}
```

Comment: This do increases readability. But what if a listener listen to more than 2 events ? ( Or maybe the best way is to ensure all the events are passing the same type of instance ? )

Comment: If you use PHPStorm you can leave out type-hinting of `$event` and use @param doc.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using PHP 8, you can take adventage of Union Types.

```
class BillListener
    {
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param FoodWasPurchased|DrinksWasPurchased $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(FoodWasPurchased|DrinksWasPurchased $event): void
    {
        // Listener code goes here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1- Add to EventServiceProvider:

```
'App\Events\NewMessageSent' => [
    'App\Listeners\SendNewMessageNotificationToRecipients',
],
'App\Events\MessageReplied' => [
    'App\Listeners\SendNewMessageNotificationToRecipients',
],
'App\Events\MessageForwarded' => [
    'App\Listeners\SendNewMessageNotificationToRecipients',
],
```

2- Generate events and listener:

```
php artisan event:generate
```

3- On SendNewMessageNotificationToRecipients.php (listener):

```
use App\Events\Event;
use App\Events\NewMessageSent;
use App\Events\MessageReplied;
use App\Events\MessageForwarded;

public function handle(Event $event)
{
    if ($event instanceof NewMessageSent) {
        dd('message sent');
    } else if ($event instanceof MessageReplied) {
        dd('message replied');
    } else if ($event instanceof MessageForwarded) {
       dd('message forwarded');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the following of `@The Alpha` answer and simplifying it:

First, create an `interface` and implement the interface in each `Event`.

```php
interface BillPublihed {}
```

And here are our events implementing it:

```php
class FoodPurchased implements BillPublished {}
class FoodPurchased implements BillPublished {}
```

The Listener gets the interface in the handle method:

```php
class BillListener {
   public function handle(BillPublished $event) {...}
}
```

This is the main difference. No need to listen/subscribe to other events.
It should only listen to the `interface`.
So in the `EventServiceProvider` we'll have:

```php
protected $listen = [
    //...
    BillPublished::class => [BillListener::class],
    //...
];
```

And if you dispatch `FoodPurchaced` or `DrinkPurchased` or any event implementing the `BillPublished` interface, the `BillListener` will be triggered without extra effort.